# Grab all results of async anonymous function using forEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, async-await

```js
async function multiply(task) {
  return task * 2
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

var res = [];
arr.forEach(async task => {
  res.push(await multiply(task))
});

console.log(res)
```

#### Output

```
[]
```

#### Expected

```
[2,4,6,8]
```

I want to wait till all the items have been multiplied by 2 and then get the result as an array.

**NOTE:** `multiply` is an asynchronous function therefore it is necessary to write `async task`  inside forEach. I can not change multiply.

Comment: I'm hoping your actual problem involves something truely async in `multiply`, otherwise you're simply adding overhead to a sychronous problem. - this won't allow you to "multi-thread".

Comment: As Aku would say, *an `async` callback for `forEach` never does what you think it does*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `forEach`. Use `.map` to create an array of promises and use `Promise.all` to resolve all of them:

```
const result = await Promise.all(arr.map(multiply));
```

---

`forEach` is not aware of asynchronous functions, so you can't make it "wait" for async stuff that happens inside its callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this will help, instead of `forEach` use the `map` and `Promise.all` functions.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// Create an array of promises
var result = arr.map(async task => {
  return await multiply(task);
});

// Use Promise.all that returns a promise that resolves to an array of the results of the input promises 
Promise.all(result).then((res) => console.log("my result", res));

async function multiply(task) {
  return task * 2
}
```